# strtok_r results in segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

This code is to parse a csv file, but it results in segmentation fault.
I could see the similar code here: [Nested strtok function problem in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693884/nested-strtok-function-problem-in-c?rq=1)

They look same but my code results in segmentation fault. Why?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct inputTuple{
    int user, item, rating;
};

int main(void)
{
    char xdata[] = "1,88,0,874965758;1,2,1,876893171;1,99,1,878542960;";
    vector<inputTuple> input;

            int maxUser = 0, maxItem = 0;
        int user, item, rating;

        char *end_str;
        char *data_point = strtok_r(xdata, ";", &end_str);

        while(data_point != NULL) {
            char *end_attr;
            char *data_point_attr = strtok_r(data_point, ",", &end_attr);
            while(data_point_attr != NULL) {

                user = atoi(data_point_attr);
                data_point_attr = strtok_r(NULL, ",", &end_attr);
                item = atoi(data_point_attr);
                data_point_attr = strtok_r(NULL, ",", &end_attr);
                rating = atoi(data_point_attr);
                strtok_r(NULL, ",", &end_attr);
                input.push_back({user, item, rating});
                maxUser = max(maxUser, user);
                maxItem = max(maxItem, item);
                }
            data_point = strtok_r(NULL, ";", &end_str);
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `strtok()` in c++. And not necessarily it's `strtok()`'s fault.

Comment: Have you tried to debug?

Comment: I have the constraint to use that. Under Intel SGX enclave.

Comment: if a line doesn't have all the fields `data_point_attr = strtok_r(NULL, ",", &end_attr);` returns `NULL` and `atoi` triggers a segfault, which may be the case on the last token

Comment: No, does not work even if I remove ; from last.
 http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dee251b2308b7cb9

Comment: sorry cannot compile because my gcc doesn't have strtok_r... you really should use a C++ method to split strings...

Comment: [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) is your friend here.  Se how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16446665/c-read-from-csv-file)

Comment: I cannot use stringstream. Under Intel SGX

Comment: yeah: there are some NULL pointers here: check my assert fails at line 56 here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/490160980cfa660f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your inner loop is not needed AND toxic to your program.

The inner loop extracts 3 tokens, then continues, extract the 4th token but reaches `NULL` in the middle, and `atoi` is passed `NULL`: segfault.

You only need one loop (added `assert` statements for sanity though):

```
    while(data_point != NULL) {
        char *end_attr;
        char *data_point_attr = strtok_r(data_point, ",", &end_attr);

            user = atoi(data_point_attr);
            data_point_attr = strtok_r(NULL, ",", &end_attr);
            assert(data_point_attr != NULL);
            item = atoi(data_point_attr);
            data_point_attr = strtok_r(NULL, ",", &end_attr);
            assert(data_point_attr != NULL);
            rating = atoi(data_point_attr);
            strtok_r(NULL, ",", &end_attr);
            input.push_back({user, item, rating});
            maxUser = max(maxUser, user);
            maxItem = max(maxItem, item);

        data_point = strtok_r(NULL, ";", &end_str);
    }
```

A better solution would be to use a real C++ solution to split the strings.

Answer (score 2):

Jean-Francois is correct. Just check the value before calling `atoi` like below. You need to do that every time you are calling `atoi`

```
if(data_point_attr != NULL)
    user = atoi(data_point_attr);
```

Comment: ok, but the inner loop is the issue. Protecting against NULL will create one entry too much in the `vector`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, yes you are right. I have up voted you :-)

Answer (score 2):

According to Valgrind, your program is failing here:

```
                item = atoi(data_point_attr);
```

, as a result of the function argument being NULL.  This seems to be consistent with Jean-François's prediction.  A bit of debugging with gdb shows that it occurs on the second loop iteration, though you could have determined that even via print-statement debugging.  And just a bit more debugging with gdb shows what's going on: your inner loop is faulty, because the loop condition does not become false when you reach the end of a record.

And what do you need that inner loop for, anyway?  Nothing.  You are reading each value via a separate statement, so you've effectively unrolled the loop *vs.* what one would need in a program to consume *arbitrary* CSV.  **Do** check the result of each `strtok_r()` call, but drop the unneeded inner loop.